# using order method in third association field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

```
class Order
  has_many :order_details
end

class OrderDetail
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :person
end

class Person
  has_one :profile
  delegate :first_name, last_name
end

class Profile

end
```

I'm currently iterating the order details in my view and try to sort or order by last name
how can I achieve this?

I'm using this in my view

```
@order_details.joins(:person).order('last_name ASC').each do |detail|
```

should I use sort? or order?

this is my error

```
column "last_name" does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@order_details.joins(order: :person).order('last_name ASC')
```

should do the trick.

The reason is you do not have direct association to person from order_details (it is via order). It is called Nested Join and you can reference API [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/joins)

The names passed to joins methods are not the table names, they are association names.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the table name to the the order cause:

```
@order_details.joins(:person).order('people.last_name ASC')
```

Comment: where did you get the people?

Comment: I used `people` because would assumed that the table of the `Person` model is following Rails conventions and therefore is named `people`.

Comment: i use belongs_to person in my OrderDetail class

Comment: `person` is the name of the association and it is singular because a record can only belong to one person at the time. The table that stores all records of the `Person` model is named `people` because there are many `people` stored in that table. These are Rails' naming conventions.

Comment: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "people"

Comment: That is weird. How does your database schema look like? Did you name the table differently, for example, `persons`?

Comment: yeah, I know that but 'OrderDetail' has a different person.

Comment: OrderDetail had a person_id

Comment: @order_details.joins(order: :person).order('last_name ASC') should do the trick. The reason is you do not have direct association to person from order_details (it is via Order). It is called Nested Join and you can reference API [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/joins)

Comment: You need to pass the table name to the `order` method on which the `last_name` column was defined. How is that table named in your database?

Comment: this is new to me "joins(order: :person)" let me try this

Comment: @Tun is working but i dont have a data. i will migrate my data. give me a minute to do this. please create. an answer so i cant accept it